# Counting Triangles Between two intersecting lines

Tags: combinatorics

Two straight lines ABCDEFG and LMNPQG intersect at G as shown in the figure below. Assume that three distinct points form a triangle if and only if they are not in one straight line. How many triangles can be drawn so that the vertices lie on the points A, B, C, D, E, F, G, P, Q, N, M, and L which are in the straight line?

I came across this question when I was an undergrad.

I failed this one, but those who passed it gave two different methods.

Can someone remind me?

Of course one of it was like this (possibly not correct) : $$ ^{12} C _{3}-^7 C_3 -^6 C _3$$ or $$ ^{12} C _{3}-^7 C_3 -^5 C _3$$

I have forgotten the other method.

Please remind me. I need the answer to this one now for me to complete my assignment in Algebraic graph theory. Thanks in anticipation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$6\cdot 5$ triangles have $G$ as a vertex. If $G$ is not a vertex then there are $v\in\{1,2\}$ vertices on the diagonal line and the remaining $ 3-v$ vertices on the horizontal base. It follows that there are
$$6\cdot 5+6\cdot{5\choose2}+{6\choose2}\cdot 5=165$$
triangles in all.

Answer (score 1):

One way is-

There are ${12 \choose 3} $ways to choose $3$ points from $12$. However, we need to exclude cases where

- All three points are on line $ABCDEFG$: $7 \choose 3$ ways
- All three points are on line $LMNPQG$: $6 \choose 3$ ways

The final answer: ${12 \choose 3}- {7 \choose 3} -{6 \choose 3}= 165$

The result is the same as Christian Blatter's answer which was derived in another way. However, given the form of the answer, this is how you friends probably did it.

Comment: @Anochor your answer is correct.